# Let only dropdown component overflow be visible in an overflow-y-scroll modal

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I have a modal component built with react, tailwind and headless-ui, which works fine until I add a dropdown box to it.

The issue here is that, when the dropdown is opened, it overflows within the modal, causing the modal to overflow further.

I want to stop the dropdown from overflowing within the modal. I want it to be visible outside the modal. Below is an image depiction of what I want:

[image]

My already existing code is the following:

```
const Modal = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <Transition appear show={props.isOpen} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog
        as="div"
        className="relative z-30"
        onClose={() => props.setOpen && props.setOpen(false)}
      >
        <Transition.Child
          as={Fragment}
          enter="ease-out duration-300"
          enterFrom="opacity-0"
          enterTo="opacity-100"
          leave="ease-in duration-200"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0"
        >
          <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-25" />
        </Transition.Child>

        <div
          className={`fixed inset-0 flex flex-col items-center justify-center overflow-y-auto py-12`}
        >
          <Transition.Child
            as={Fragment}
            enter="ease-out duration-300"
            enterFrom="opacity-0 scale-95"
            enterTo="opacity-100 scale-100"
            leave="ease-in duration-200"
            leaveFrom="opacity-100 scale-100"
            leaveTo="opacity-0 scale-95"
          >
            <Dialog.Panel
              as="div"
              className={`relative max-h-[85%] max-w-[80%] transform bg-white py-6 pr-0 text-left align-middle shadow-xl transition-all ${
                !props.disableRoundedCorners ? 'rounded-lg' : ''
              } ${props.width ?? 'w-6/12 '} ${props.height ?? 'h-[75%]'}`}
            >
              <div
                className={`h-full w-full overflow-visible ${
                  props.height && 'overflow-y-auto'
                }`}
              >
                {(!props.hideCloseButton || props.title) && (
                  <div className="sticky top-0 z-10 flex justify-between bg-white px-6 pb-4">
                    <Dialog.Title
                      as="div"
                      className="text-lg font-semibold leading-6 text-[#061941]"
                    >
                      {props.title}
                    </Dialog.Title>
                    <div className="">
                      {props.setOpen && !props.hideCloseButton && (
                        <button
                          type="button"
                          onClick={() => props.setOpen && props.setOpen(false)}
                          className="rounded-full bg-[#C4C4C4]/[.3] p-2 text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0"
                        >
                          <span className="sr-only">Close</span>
                          <Close />
                        </button>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )}
                {/* <div className=" flex flex-col px-6 ">{props.children}</div> */}
                <div className=" flex flex-col px-6 ">
                  <div className="sm:flex sm:items-start">
                    <div className="mt-3 w-full text-center sm:mt-0 sm:text-left">
                      <main className="flex flex-1 overflow-y-auto">
                        <div className="grid w-full grid-cols-2 gap-4 px-1">
                          <div className="col-span-1">
                            <label className="text-sm">Phone Number</label>
                            <Listbox
                              value={country}
                              onChange={setCountry}
                              as="div"
                              className="relative flex w-full flex-col"
                            >
                              {({ open }) => (
                                <>
                                  <div
                                    className={`input input-group flex h-full w-full py-0 px-0`}
                                  >
                                    <Listbox.Button as={Fragment}>
                                      <button
                                        className={`px-4`}
                                        disabled={props.disabled}
                                      >
                                        <FlagRenderer country={country} />
                                      </button>
                                    </Listbox.Button>
                                    <input
                                      type="tel"
                                      name="phone"
                                      placeholder="Phone Number"
                                      className="input h-full w-full rounded-l-none px-2"
                                      value={phone}
                                      onChange={handlePhoneValueChange}
                                    />
                                  </div>

                                  {open && (
                                    <div className="absolute top-14 left-0 z-10 h-32 w-full overflow-hidden rounded-lg border bg-white py-2 pl-4">
                                      <Listbox.Options className="h-full overflow-auto focus:outline-none">
                                        {countries.map(country => {
                                          return (
                                            <Listbox.Option
                                              key={country.iso2}
                                              value={country.iso2}
                                            >
                                              <div className="flex flex-nowrap justify-between pr-2">
                                                <span className="flex space-x-2">
                                                  <FlagRenderer
                                                    country={country.iso2}
                                                  />
                                                  <div>{country.name}</div>
                                                </span>
                                                <div>+{country.dialCode}</div>
                                              </div>
                                            </Listbox.Option>
                                          );
                                        })}
                                      </Listbox.Options>
                                    </div>
                                  )}
                                </>
                              )}
                            </Listbox>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </main>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </Dialog.Panel>
          </Transition.Child>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition>
  );
};
```

Comment: Where is the code for drop-down?

Comment: Consider using [a portal](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/createPortal) to have the  drop down DOM rendered outside the overflow-constrained parent. @AniketPandey the drop-down code is the `<Listbox.Options>`.

Comment: @Wongjn, I have tried your suggestion and the `<LIstbox.Options` shows at a different position on the page. No my new concern is, how do I ensure it is positioned relatively to the element that triggers it?

Comment: You'd need to set position it so that the it is positioned relatively to the element that triggers it.

Comment: would it be possible to add an answer with a sample code that works?